# Importing array of object from external file getting error: "function" is declared but its value is never read ts(6133)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, import

I have array of objects

**toDo.js**

```
export const examples = [
  {
    question: "xx",
    answer: "yy",
  },
  {
    question: "xx",
    answer: "yy",
  },....]
```

Then i have following logic and then i import it to **index.js**. by this piece of code `<div id="examples-container"></div>`  and then also i import it `<script src="logic.js" type="module"></script>`

I have following problem: **Toggle** (function) **is declared but its value is never read ts(6133)**. I'm gettin this error when i click on buttons.

**logic.js**

```
import { examples } from "./Předměty/Matematika.js";

function toggle(i) {
  const div = document.querySelector(`#result_${i}`);
  if (div.style.display !== "none") {
    div.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    div.style.display = "block";
  }
}

let html = "";
examples.forEach((ex, i) => {
  const example = `
  <div class="card">
    <div class="example">
    ${ex.question}
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="toggle" onclick="toggle(${i})">
      Toggle
    </button>
    <div id="result_${i}" style="display:none" class="result">${ex.answer}</div>
  </div>`;
  html += example;
});
const container = document.querySelector("#examples-container");
container.innerHTML = html;
```

When i consol.log(examples). I get whole array. Also i've tried create new variable and then insert the array. Whole app worked how i expected when it was in one file but now i try to split it to different files because.. U know it's standart have app devided to more then 1 big file and also i have some future plans so it will be necessary. ^^

Best
Vojtěch

Comment: Hi Petr Hasil, Thanks for your question. Normally Typescript linter do not accept any variable or function or any declaration without using it. I think you can past up the linter adding the rules off with a comment.  The next issue is that the click not working because the browser is not recognizing the toggle function, because is declared as local function. One solution is to bind it to the scope or add it as a global window calling. window.toggle = ().... Let me know if this options work

Comment: Petr Hasil, I do not know all the context of the file where the toggle button is called. If you not using any Js UI library or Js framework; You should consider to wrap your code into functions following IIFE statemen pattern. Because your code is exposed to any other js files scopes and you may drop in conflicts and how you are not using no static checker or static type notation, this can drop in many scopes issues.. If not you can move to ES using class notation or move to Typescript

Comment: Hello, window.toggle(i) is getting error: '(' expected. for dot between window and toggle and then somewhere is expected ";".  Could you be more specific please? I've started few weeks ago with programing

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the html code cannot access the `toggle` function. To fix this, you can build the DOM tree manually. So, instead of creating a string with html code in it and appending it onto the container element, you can create each element individually.

```
const container = document.querySelector("#examples-container");

examples.forEach((ex, i) => {
    // Make the div for the <div class="card">
    const card = document.createElement("div");
    // Add the "card" class to the div
    card.classList.add("card");

    // Create the div for the <div class="example">${ex.question}</div>
    const example = document.createElement("div");
    // Add the "example" class
    example.classList.add("example");
    // Set the HTML inside of it to ex.question
    example.innerHTML = ex.question;
    // Add it to the card element
    card.appendChild(example);

    // Create the button for the <button class="Toggle">Toggle</button>
    const button = document.createElement("button");
    // Add the "toggle" class to the button
    button.classList.add("toggle");
    // Set the text inside of it to say "Toggle"
    button.innerHTML = "Toggle";
    // Add the onclick event listener
    button.addEventListener("click", () => toggle(i));
    // Add the toggle button to the card
    card.appendChild(button);

    // Create the div for the <div id="result_${i}" class="result">${ex.answer}</div>
    const result = document.createElement("div");
    // Add the id for the element
    result.id = "result_" + i;
    // Hide the result element (display: none)
    result.style.display = "none";
    // Add the "result" class
    result.classList.add("result");
    // Set it's HTML to the answer
    result.innerHTML = ex.answer;
    // Add the result element to the card
    card.appendChild(result);

    // Add the card to the container
    container.appendChild(card);
});
```

Comment: Yo buddy, thanks! This works perfect. But i have absolutly no idea what's going on. Could you add here some description please?